# How to calculate correlation in spark on columns with nulls?

Tags: apache-spark, statistics, pyspark

Given a column of dense vectors with NaN entries I would like to calculate correlation between columns. Is there a way to do that without disassembling the vector for value clean up?

```
    #pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors as MlVectors # (
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

def get_data():
  spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
      (Vectors.dense(1., 3., 2.), 0),
      (Vectors.dense(None, 4., 1.), 1),
      (Vectors.dense(3., None, 0.), 2),
      (Vectors.dense(4., 12., None), 3),
      (Vectors.dense(5., 0., 1.), 5),
      (Vectors.dense(6., -1., 0.), 6)], ["features", "foo"])
  return df


def correlation(df):
  digestible_data = df.select("features").rdd.map(lambda row: MlVectors.dense(row[0]))
  print(Statistics.corr(digestible_data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    correlation(get_data())
# OUTPUT:
# [[  1.  nan  nan]
#  [ nan   1.  nan]
#  [ nan  nan   1.]]
```

Comment: I am only interested in the last column (row) of the output matrix, but this is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see no-one wants to deep into this. So, here is a solution as slow as it is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors as MlVectors # (
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
import numpy as np

def get_data():
  spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
      (Vectors.dense(1., 3., 2.), 0),
      (Vectors.dense(None, 4., 1.), 1),
      (Vectors.dense(3., None, 0.), 2),
      (Vectors.dense(4., 12., None), 3),
      (Vectors.dense(5., 0., 1.), 5),
      (Vectors.dense(6., -1., 0.), 6)], ["features", "foo"])
  return df


def correlation(df):
  digestible_data = df.select("features").rdd.map(lambda row: MlVectors.dense(row[0]))
  print(Statistics.corr(digestible_data))


def nullproofed_correlation(df, column='features'):
  num_colls = len(df.head()[column])
  res = np.ones((num_colls, num_colls), dtype=np.float32)
  for i in range(1, num_colls):
    for j in range(i):
      feature_pair_df = df.select("features").rdd.map(lambda x: MlVectors.dense([x[0][i], x[0][j]]))
      feature_pair_df = feature_pair_df.filter(lambda x: not np.isnan(x[0]) and not np.isnan(x[1]))
      corr_matrix = Statistics.corr(feature_pair_df, method="pearson")
      corr = corr_matrix[0, 1]
      res[i, j], res[j, i] = corr, corr
  print(res)
  return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(correlation(get_data()))
  print(nullproofed_correlation(get_data()))
```

Generally speaking, correlation can only be calculated on existing data. So it would make sense to create a new column indicating whether value was present or not and then calculate only for present data. And use "presense" information as additional feature somewhere else. Unfortunately, spark correlation provides no help when working with sparse data.